# What are the implications of the Bank of England directly financing government spending?

Tags: united-kingdom, economy, covid-19, central-bank

HM Treasury has [announced](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/hm-treasury-and-bank-of-england-announce-temporary-extension-of-the-ways-and-means-facility) this morning (April 9th) that the UK has temporarily extended the Ways and Means facility (the government's overdraft with the BoE) in order to fund the fight against the COVID-19 pandemic. As I understand it, this allows the government to obtain cash directly from the Bank of England, without having to rely on the bond market; although the statement does say that "The government will continue to use the markets as its primary source of financing".

Is my understanding of the measure correct, and is this move equivalent to measures taken in post-WWI Germany and Zimbabwe, as suggested by the [Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/business/2020/04/09/bank-england-temporarily-finance-government-spending/)? What are the implications of such a move?

Comment: On econ SE there are quite a few of those questions. At least there there's enough mass of experts to downvote the nonsense. Here, past experience with the econ questions has shown me the opposite is the case. You''ll get "shoot from the hip" answers that will get tons of HNQ upvotes, despite being factually wrong (on questions like this).

Comment: @Fizz Fair enough - the thing that spurred me to add that part was the [Telegraph's article](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/business/2020/04/09/bank-england-temporarily-finance-government-spending/) on this, which refers to it leading to "the permanent funding of government spending, linked to hyperinflation in post First World War Germany and more recently in Zimbabwe.". The FT also linked this to Zimbabwe-esque measures, but they seem to have removed that section from their article now.

Comment: Would it not make a difference that is a _temporary_ overdraft, and the government intends to pay it back by the end of the year? In any case, [this BBC article](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/business-52226482) addresses some of the issues mentioned in the question.

Comment: Ah yeah... the hyperinflation fear. I was pretty sure that was behind your question as it's a popular theme lately...  https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/34656/what-amount-of-quantitative-easing-will-cause-hyperinflation